# I am trying to compare two number using Sql query. for e.g 123.45 and 12345 are same if i ignore decimal so it should come in output

Tags: sql

I am trying to compare two string using Sql query. for e.g In table A i have A123.45 and in table B i have A12345. this two string are same if i ignore decimal point so as a output i would want table A's value.

Comment: what kind of question is this? because `123.45 <> 12345`. Under this logic `1 = 2`  if you divide `2/2`. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Cast them to strings, replace the '.' with '', and compare. This will not be fast. Perhaps there are some other criteria you've forgotten to mention, like 123.45 is a money value in dollars and 12345 is a value in cents - that would make a difference in how to solve the problem.

Comment: @AndrewMorton You beat me to this I guess, I just put that in an answer independently :)

Comment: @EJoshuaS No problem. It *could* be that comparing theInteger to (theFloat * 100) would be valid, and it would be much faster, but without more information we cannot say.

Comment: @AndrewMorton That's true, that could work if you knew in advance how many decimal places there will be. It would definitely be helpful if this question had more context. This could also be an instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (but again it's hard to say without more information).

Comment: Thank You for reply.It is not money value. It is ICD code. so In one of my table i have code with decimal and in other table i have code without decimal. so if i ignore decimal they have same meaning. so i want compare if they are same or not. does this make sense?

Comment: @SaraswatiD. 1) ICD codes are not really numbers: they are strings which just happen to use only digits. 2) Please edit your question to include that information - it might stop your question from being closed.

Comment: @SaraswatiD. If that's the case you can just strip out the decimal (if there is one) and compare the strings like I do in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, to avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), it's a little unclear to me why you'd want to do this in the first place - I'm not sure exactly why 123.45 *should* be equal to 12345. Definitely something to think about.

With that said, if you insist, you can do something like the following:

```
select case when replace(cast(floatingPointNumber as varchar(50)), '.', '') = cast(yourInteger as varchar(50)) then 1 else 0 end
from YourTable
```

Obviously, `floatingPointNumber` is a float and `yourInteger` is an integer.

I'm not sure what platform you're using since you didn't tag it but I wrote/tested this in SQL Server. You can do something similar in Oracle/MySQL if that's what you're using.

Basically, what this is doing is casting both the floating point number and the integer to strings, removing the decimal from the floating point number, and comparing them. If they're equal, it returns 1; otherwise it returns 0.